# parameter assignment of callback method in android

Tags: java, android, methods, callback

There are some callback methods in android, like "onCreate" or "onClick".

I have a question about them.
When those callback methods show up in programs,
their parameters are not assigned by programmer.
Should they be assigned first?

For example,

```
Bundle  saveInstanceState = something; 
//assign parameter saveInstanceState first. (yet not assigned in real case)
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
// do something .....
};
```

or

```
View v = something; 
//assign parameter v first. (yet not assgned in real case)
public void onClick(View v)  {
// do something .....
};
```

All the codes I have read so far don't assign "saveInstanceState"(of onCreate) or 
"v"(of onClick) by the programmers.

Does that mean "android will assign those parameters of callback methods itself"?
If so, are all parameters of all callback methods the same case?

For example, "data and camera in onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {};",
are they assigned by android system automatically and programmer doesn't need to assign them?

I can't find relative details in android developer website so far.
If a parameter is assigned by system, not by programmer, 
why is there no relative guideline or note about that in android developer website document?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: You don't have to assign those parameters, no. You can just use them, although be aware that they can be null in some cases!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters of a function are assigned by the caller of the function. Example:

```
int x = 0;

public void test(int x)
{
   System.out.println(x);
   System.out.println(this.x);
}

test(2);
//prints
//2
//0
```

So in your case

```
View v = something; 
//assign parameter v first. (yet not assgned in real case)
public void onClick(View v)  {
// do something .....
};
```

v and this.v would reference different objects inside the onClick method body.

Comment: I might get what you mean.

Comment: I might get what you meant. The Programmer defines his callback methods. Yet the caller of the methods is the system. So system will assign the parameters when it calls callback methods. The programmer doesn't need to do anything about the assignment of those parameters.